# Regex Select numeric string between elements

Tags: html, regex

I have been searching stack and Google and have figured out some of what I'm trying to do. Here is the string

```
?w=2796&
```

I need to get the numerics between `w=` and `&`

So it should return `w=2796`

Here's what I have so far: `w=(.*?)&`

This does work but is returning the `&`

Is there a way to to return only `w=numeric`

This regex is also returning some other elements which I don't need in the HTML in some instances.

Comment: I am using this website to test - http://regexr.com/ and it's only returning w=. Thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: Ahead of you already ;p got rid of the `?`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: Is that a better way of doing it? Could you give me an example of doing it that way? The way I had is returning unneeded data at times with other params set to w=

Comment: That would depend on the language you are using.

Comment: ***"I need to get the numerics between w= and &" ..."So it should return `w=2796`"***  Do you read what you write ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to depend on which regex engine you use. & may have special meaning. I think the simplest approach here is something like `/w=(\d+)/` or `/w=([0-9]+)/` assuming no negatives or decimals in your numbers

Comment: I am unclear as to what regex engine this software is using. It's actually a program called Scrapebox which allows you to use regex. I have tried both /w=(\d+)/ AND /w=([0-9]+)/ which will not return any results. When I use w=([^&]*) it does return results but returns a bunch of other HTML I don't need. Do you think it could because of the engine this software is using?

Comment: @JoeZ, remove the `/`, they are just to indicate regex... but if you are putting into a regex input field they will be unnecessary

Comment: Thank you! I have this working and returning exactly what is needed. Thank you for the tip of not including the /